# VBScript to call JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, photoshop-script

Going out on a limb here. Is there a way for a Photoshop VBScript to call a JavaScript file?

Or at least pass some user input (variable or return from function) from one script to another.

My reason for this? I've been having similar issues asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877179/dialog-box-does-not-have-a-constructor) and considered a VBScript UI to drive a photoshop-script. Re-writing the existing jsx into VBS isn't really an option.

Here's what I have. This simple VBScript asks for the user to type in their name which is then created as text in the second script.

**VBScript**

```
' Ask User for input
Dim appRef
Set appRef = CreateObject( "Photoshop.Application" )

Dim askName : askName = InputBox("Enter name: ")
```

**JavaScript**

```
// create a document to work with
var docRef = app.documents.add(200, 100, 72, "Hello");

// Create a new art layer containing text
var artLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
artLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;

// Set the contents of the text layer.
var textItemRef = artLayerRef.textItem
textItemRef.contents = "Hello " + askName
```

What do I need to connect the two up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience in scripting with Photoshop, did some research.

The following code has been tested with Adobe Photoshop® CS6.

`PsJavaScriptExecutionMode` enum constants are extracted from `scriptingsupport.8li` (Adobe Photoshop CS6 Object Library) by using Microsoft OLE/COM Object Viewer.

**VBScript:**

```vb
'PsJavaScriptExecutionMode Enums
Const psNeverShowDebugger = 1, psDebuggerOnError = 2, psBeforeRunning = 3

Dim appRef
Set appRef = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")

Dim askName
    askName = InputBox("Enter name: ")

appRef.DoJavaScriptFile "C:\scripts\myPSscript.jsx", Array(askName), psNeverShowDebugger
```

**JavaScript (myPSscript.jsx):**

```js
// create a document to work with
var docRef = app.documents.add(200, 100, 72, "Hello");

// Create a new art layer containing text
var artLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
artLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;

// Set the contents of the text layer.
var textItemRef = artLayerRef.textItem
var askName = arguments[0]; // first argument passed from VBScript
textItemRef.contents = "Hello " + askName;
```

Hope it helps.

---

[Adobe® Creative Suite® 5 Photoshop® Scripting Guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20170329014311if_/http://wwwimages.adobe.com:80/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_scripting_guide.pdf)

Comment: It worked! - just as long as you don't have the VBscript & PScript called the same ie test.vbs & test,jsx

Comment: @GhoulFool Sorry I couldn't understand. What was the question then?

Comment: No question. It's all good :) The code worked. But the first time I tried I named both files the same C:\scripts\myPSscript.jsx & C:\scripts\myPSscript.vbs and that came up with an error. By renaming the VBS to C:\scripts\myscript.vbs Does that make sense now?

Comment: @GhoulFool It's important to know what the error message says. I couldn't reproduce the issue. It was probably a `file not found error` due to a typo, I think.